# How can I clone the child menu of a menu item?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I've already figured out how to clone the hole menu item, but if I click it, it first opens the name of the menu item name (*general* in this example) and then it shows me the submenu (child menu). 
This is what I have for now:

```
Private Sub ConstruirContextMenu(ByVal MenuItem As System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem)

    Dim cmEdit = New ContextMenu
    cmEdit.MenuItems.Add(MenuItem.CloneMenu())
    'Set ContextMenu component of form
    ContextMenu = cmEdit

End Sub
```

And this is the code that calls that sub:

```
Private Sub Image_mnuGeneral_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Image_mnuGeneral.Click, Text_mnuGeneral.Click


    ConstruirContextMenu(Me.MainMenu.MenuItems(0))
    'Me.MainMenu.MenuItems(0).Visible = False

    ContextMenu.Show(Me.Image_mnuGeneral, New System.Drawing.Point(Me.UWP_PanelMenu.Width, 0))

    TratarOpcionesUWPMenu(UWPMenu_General)

End Sub
```

I'll put a photo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hWLL.png) to explain better what I need.
I need that, when the item in the black menu is clicked, only the submenu displays, directly.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english & explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolve it with adding a simple `For Each` in the `ConstruirContextMenu Sub`. 
I've done something like this and it worked:

```
Private Sub ConstruirContextMenu(ByVal MenuItem As System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem)

    Dim cmEdit = New ContextMenu
    For Each SubMenu As System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem In MenuItem.MenuItems
        cmEdit.MenuItems.Add(SubMenu.CloneMenu())
    Next

    'Set ContextMenu component of form
    ContextMenu = cmEdit

End Sub
```

Such a simple way to resolve it but it worked.